# Swift Nav Bar with Title and Page Control

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a swift app but having some problem on putting title and page control, together on the nav bar. I only manage to put either one of them on the nav bar, but not both. I am hoping for something like this(as well as the animation when swiping to another view controller) :

[image]

Below is my screen output. Page controller(embedded in Navigation controller) is working, just wanted to add titles(change base on view) and page control.

[image]

And here's how I create the title:

This is how I create the title:

```
@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationItem!

let title: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44))
title.numberOfLines = 2
title.textAlignment = .Center
title.text = "News\n"
navBar.titleView = title
```

I am making the title into 2 lines to leave room for the page control. However, when I try to create page control programmatically, it appears to be "behind" the nav bar.

This is how create page control:

```
let pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44))
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
```

Comment: You have to create custom navigation bar. What you have tried so far? Add some code.

Comment: Added codes to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Add both your label and page control to another view, setting the constraints / frames appropriately, then add that view as the `titleView` for the nav bar.